# Is it possible to call WebApi inside Middleware Asp .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm workin on a MVC Aps.Net Core project and I have this situation :

> User **A** is loggedin device **A**, and user **B** is trying to login in device **A**. I allow to login the user **B** to device **A** without problem, but in that case I show pop-up message to user **A** that user **A** now is disconected from device **A**.

Evrithing works fine. I call WebApi where I have SQL function, and that function do all the job. The problem is that I have the same code(that call the WebApi) in each function on my project. So I was thinking to make custom middleware so in that way I don't need to replace that code in every function/method in my project.

This is what I tried :

```
 public class Middleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        string strBaseUrl = string.Empty;
        string strMappaturaUrl = string.Empty;
        private readonly IConfiguration config;
        private readonly HttpClient client;

        public Middleware(RequestDelegate next, IConfiguration _config, HttpClient _client)
        {
            _next = next;
            client = _client;
            config = _config;
            strBaseUrl = config.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:BaseUrl");
            strMappaturaUrl = config.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:MapUrl");
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            string returnErrore = string.Empty;
            CheckUtenteDTO userRequest = new CheckUtenteDTO();
            string strUrlApi = string.Empty;
            string strContext = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                userRequest.user = HttpContext.Session.GetString("nomeUten");
                userRequest.macchina = HttpContext.Session.GetString("macchina");

                //Here I call WebApi where I have SQL functio
                strUrlApi = config.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:BaseUrl") + "/Users/CheckLoginUser";

                string stringData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userRequest);
                var contentData = new StringContent(stringData, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                using (var responseMessage = await client.PostAsync(strUrlApi, contentData))
                {
                    if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        strContext = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var strReturn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(strContext);

                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strReturn))
                            returnErrore = string.Empty;
                        else
                            throw new UtenteException(strReturn);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strContext = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        throw new Exception(strContext);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (UserException ex1)
            {
                returnErrore = ex1.Message.Trim();
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("strErrore", ex1.Message);
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("nextAction", "LogoutAfterCheck");
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("nextController", "Login");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                returnErrore = ex.Message.Trim();
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("strErrore", ex.Message);
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("nextAction", "Index");
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("nextController", "HomeScreen");
            }

            return Json(returnErrore);
            //return _next(httpContext);
        }

    }

    // Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
    public static class MiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<Middleware>();
        }
    }
}
```

And I get this [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMs5R.png) .

Is it possible to do it in this way?
Any suggestions how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That looks like your middleware don't have access to `HttpContext` and thus the error. In such case, you can pass the context as a parameter to your middleware from your presentation layer where you have access to HttpContext and calling the Middleware function.

Essentially, you are using only the below two parameters from session .. then why not just extract them in your presentation layer and pass them as argument to the middleware function

```
userRequest.user = HttpContext.Session.GetString("nomeUten");
userRequest.macchina = HttpContext.Session.GetString("macchina");
```

Change your `Invoke` method signature to

```
Task Invoke(string user, string macchina) //assuming both are type string
```